# From C# analysis to Java analysis with Roslyn

Tags: java, c#, dll, package, roslyn

My question is purely theoretical, and if it's a positive answer, I'd like to implement it later.

Could it be possible to create code analysis with Roslyn and store it in a dll and then use the content from that dll in a JVM-based project?
I know there some similarities between Visual C# and the Java language. But being enable to only analyze C# and VB for the moment (I think F# has been put on hold for the moment), could it apply code analysis from C# to Java when the have the exact functionalities (like loops for instance).

From [this post](http://codefry.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/calling-net-dlls-from-java-code-without.html), I get that dlls can be call using Java. I would be happy to know that when I'm going through the syntax tree when I'm using VB or C#,it could do the same for Java or even Kotlin which is more similar to C#.

Comment: What do you mean by "store it in a DLL"?

Comment: @QualityCatalyst I think OP is trying to say "build source code into a .net library assembly (.dll file)"

Comment: @QualityCatalyst Well usually, as you might already know, a project outputs either a .exe, a dll or a module. I made some analyzers at work and the output has been saved as a dll. I would like to do my own at home and have a similar ouput.

Comment: @kiroYakuza, by code analysis what I mean is to use the compiler platform and go through the syntax tree to evaluate syntax nodes in order to either enforce coding behaviors that should be met in certain situations and even provide cod fixes when there's code that be easily fixed (adding an argument to make sure that the user uses the good overload of a method)

Comment: @KiroYakuza, I had not seen your post about what I meant. That's exactly what I meant !

Comment: You want to try and analyze Java code with Roslyn? That seems like trying to jam a square peg in a round hole.

Comment: @Kavignon I took a quick look a roslyn in google and if you're hoping that the code analyzer would be able to analyze the java side of your code, I don't think it would work since it's a .net analyzer. BTW what would the functional use of multi-language programming be if you aren't already trying using establish libraries and really want them in your project?

Comment: @mikez being that .net assembly dlls can be called  with JVM based languages and that when writting a compiler using C#, it can analyze VB code, I thought that the logical analyzation that I created could be used when using those type of languages with could bring us closer to the code once use everywhere :-)

Comment: @KiroYakuza I'm a Java and C# dev. Working with the platform compiler made me realize that only making it work on .net is fun but it could better (for me) if I could use this functionality in my other projects where I develop desktop java application or an android application.

Comment: @Kavignon Sure you can write a code analysis for VB in C# with Roslyn because Roslyn knows what VB is. It doesn't know what Java is. I would expect analysis of all but the most trivial Java fragments to fail.

Comment: See, that what I wanted to know. @mikez 
In my head, I thought that being similar to C#, Kotlin and Java might have been enable to use analyzers and code fixes from Roslyn.
If you could explain your comment in a short answer, I'll close this thread !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood the role of Roslyn. The purpose was to expose the wealth of information the C# and VB.NET compilers have on the program structure to the authors of developer tools for the languages. To quote [Eric Lippert](http://www.i-programmer.info/professional-programmer/i-programmer/7154-c-guru-an-interview-with-eric-lippert.html?start=1):

> Roslyn is a class library usable from C#, VB or other managed languages. Its purpose is to enable analysis of C# and VB code.

and

> It is not a mechanism for customers to themselves extend the C# or VB languages; it is a mechanism for analyzing the existing languages.

Roslyn is most certainly not a mechanism to analyze Java because it was not written to analyze Java. It was written analyze a somewhat similar language, C# (the similarity is by design, the language authors wanted it to be somewhat familiar to existing C/C++/Java programmers). However, all but the most trivial fragments of Java are not valid C#. It is not just esoteric features like generic constraints and wildcards, but core methods like `Equals` have different casings in the two. It is unlikely that a Java fragment of any significant size or complexity could be analyzed by Roslyn.